# 2 forms - How to layout overlapping elements

Tags: html, css, forms

Given 2 forms on 1 page, I want some elements in form #2 to be side by side with some elements in form #1.  Haven't been able to figure this one out, as my elements in form #2 always fall underneath the end of form #1. Also I need to keep my form #2 element structure in tact as it is coming from an outside library.

```
<form name="form1">
    <textarea rows="10" name="tabTxBx" id="tabTxtArea" cols="50" wrap="off" ></textarea><br><br>
    Captcha image here<br>
    Type capture image:<br>
    <input type="text"><br><br>
</form>
<table width="400">
    <tr>
        <td width="200">
               <input type="submit" value="  save  "> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- BEGIN: Can't alter this structure -->
            <form name='form2' method="POST" action="" onSubmit="return submitPlay();" target="sndWin">
                I want this right aligned under the textarea
                <input type="text" size="55" value="I want this right aligned under the textarea">
                <input type="button" value="I want this right aligned under the textarea">
            </form>
           <!-- END: Can't alter this structure -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also note:
I can't break up form #2 and need to avoid HTML5 features for the time being (for older browser support).

JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z562wx2c/5/

Comment: Not sure if I have it correct but you could use some CSS [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/digiman07/ngmxkvg2/)

Comment: Pretty close...Is there a way to do it without form2 coordinates hardcoded and have form2 so it follows the textarea up/down on screen when the user resizes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the forms display with css and drag the second form back into the first with position relative. I updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/z562wx2c/8/

Style to please Stackoverflows need to see code:

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: 105px;
    left: 170px;
}
```

Like that?

You might wanna use normal height and width for textarea, because "modern" browsers like firefox has serious issues with cols and rows.

Comment: ok, then make the forms display: inline; so they don't break your layout

Comment: You need HTML5 for nested forms support, so.. you're outa luck afaik.

Comment: Maybe you should write what you are trying to achieve, i'm sure theres a better way :)

Comment: Surely there's a way with CSS to reposition the forms where I need them?

Comment: Yeah, but you said you needed form2 inside form1 ? ..you meant only visually?

Comment: I used a div instead of the table, didn't touch the form structure according to your comments, just dragged the form back into place with relative position, hope that satisfies your needs :)

Comment: You got it buddy, thank you so much!  Cleaning up some of the defunct comments... :P